# AngularJS routing not working, but no errors are thrown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, routes, angularjs-routing

I'm following this [video tutorial](http://app.pluralsight.com/training/player?author=scott-allen&name=angularjs-get-started-m5-routing&mode=live&clip=0&course=angularjs-get-started) and messed something up in the haste.. The problem is that I got rid of *all* the errors I made, but it still doesn't work as expected. The search form box doesn't display.

Full code can be found here: [plnkr code](http://plnkr.co/edit/KyMnxW?p=preview)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="githubViewer">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script scr="app.js"></script>
    <script src="MainController.js"></script>
    <script src="github.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <h1>Gihub Viewer</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module("githubViewer", ["ngRoute"]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when("/main", {
        templateUrl: "main.html",
        controller: "MainController"
        })
      .otherwise({redirectTo:"/main"});
  });

}());
```

**main.html**

```
<div>
  {{ countdown }}
  <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
    <input type="search" required="" placeholder="Username to find" 
      ng-model="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are redefinig the module in the controller and factory code:

```
var app = angular.module("githubViewer",[]);
```

Instead of `getting`the created module:

```
var app = angular.module("githubViewer");
```

A module should be created once, then retrieve and add the controller, config, factory, etc...

[Here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y023) some help.

Comment: Thank you and a very useful link!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide) you can get another useful Angular style guide

Answer (score 2):

Basically you all js file has wrong IIFE pattern.wrong

It should be

```
})();
```

instead of

```
}());
```

Also there are typos. In index.html:

```
<script scr="app.js"></script>
```

Must be:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And in MainController.js. This code:

```
app.controller("MainControler", MainController);
```

Must be changed to:

```
app.controller("MainController", MainController);
```

Comment: Updated the code http://plnkr.co/edit/KyMnxW?p=preview but it doesn't seem to be it. Still not working

Comment: @Norfeldt check the edit which has been done by `Kostya Shkryob` Thanks man for edit

Comment: Thx a lot for finding all these typos. Updated the code. But still not working or throwing any errors. http://plnkr.co/edit/KyMnxW?p=preview

Comment: I have made working version of plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UV4Wzqx4vEsRdWAAMslE?p=preview

Comment: @KostyaShkryob Thanks for finding and appreciate your contribution to this answer.. :)

Comment: Wow, @KostyaShkryob you are blazing fast. It's only 26 min after I posted by question.. Thank you!  What was I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay.. found that I shouldnt add the [ ] - only did that because it was a suggestion in the console error

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how to implement a module and a controller. In both MainController.js and app.js, you have the line:

var app = angular.module("githubViewer", ["ngRoute"]);

`angular.module` actually creates a new module. You are effectively trying to create two modules with the same name, which isn't allowed.

The pattern to follow is

```
var app = angular.module(...)

app.config(...)

var controller = app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", function() {
 ]]);
```

If you really want the `MainController` code to be in a separate file, create a function:

```
 function createMainController(app) {
      app.contoller("MainController", ...)
 }
```

Comment: No..its not what you are saying..OP has declared module only once & then he is utilizing it using `angular.module('githubViewer')`